# Codeigniter using SELECT_SUM, only returning the first column

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to get the value of how many dishes are in each order of the logged-in user, by adding up the quantity of dishes group by order.

The normal query I run which is a success by assuming logged in user's userid is 35:

```
SELECT      o.orderid, location, status, pay, total, 
            SUM(quantity) AS dishnum 
FROM        orders o 
JOIN        ordersdish od 
            ON od.orderid = o.orderid 
WHERE       userid = 35 
GROUP BY    o.orderid;
```

**Result:**

[image]

Codeigniter code I tried to run:

```
public function getorderself(){
    $this->db->select_sum('quantity');
    $this->db->select('orders.orderid','location','status','pay','total');
    $this->db->from ('orders');
    $this->db->join('ordersdish', 'ordersdish.orderid = orders.orderid');
    $this->db->where('userid', $_SESSION["userid"]);
    $this->db->GROUP_BY('orders.orderid');
    $query = $this->db->get ();
    return $query;
}
```

Thank you.
Update: I changed a bit my code, it can return data but only the orderid.

Code i used in view:

```
<?php
    if($orderdata->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($orderdata->result() as $row)
        {
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->orderid; ?></td>                        
                <td><?php echo $row->location; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->status; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->pay; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->total; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->quantity; ?><td>
                <td><button type="button" href="#" class="delete_data delButton" orderid="<?php echo $row->orderid; ?>">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
<?php  

        }
    }
    else
    {
?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" align="center">No Data Founds</td>
        </tr>
<?php   
    }
?>
```

Code I used in `maim.php`

```
public function vieworderself()
{

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->model->caltotal();
    $data["orderdata"]=$this->model->getorderself();  
    $this->load->view('/orders/vieworderself', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: ***typo*** `this->db-GROUP_BY('order.orderid');` missing `>` near `db`

Comment: Duplicate to [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Sorry for the careless mistake, but the code still not work, I guess my code is having problem on line "this->db->select_sum('quantity');"

Comment: @abcsgss123 do you have the column `quantity` in table ? which column shows the number of dishes ordered?

Comment: Yes, i have column 'quantity' in table 'ordersdish'

Comment: @abcsgss123 you missed to write `$query->result();` after `$this->db->get()` i think

Comment: @abcsgss123 specify the `table_name` before every `column_name` like you did with `order.orderid`

Answer (score 0):

Try using table name before every column. Eg. orders.location

```
public function getorderself(){
    $this->db->select_sum('quantity');
    $this->db->select('orders.orderid','orders.location','orders.status','orders.pay','orders.total');
    $this->db->from ('orders');
    $this->db->join('ordersdish', 'ordersdish.orderid = orders.orderid');
    $this->db->where('orders.userid', $_SESSION["userid"]);
    $this->db->GROUP_BY('orders.orderid');
    $query = $this->db->get ();
    return $query;
}
```